# Cannot connect to Windows 10 via smbclient because of the wrong password

Tags: windows, smb, smbclient

I downloaded the samba package from arch (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba#Client)

Then I enabled *Network discovery* as described in this article: https://websiteforstudents.com/access-windows-10-files-ubuntu-17-04/

I also made sure my Windows 10 *workstation domain* is **WORKGROUP**

Then I went back to arch and created the needed config in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` with the content of https://git.samba.org/samba.git/?p=samba.git;a=blob_plain;f=examples/smb.conf.default;hb=HEAD (recommended by Arch)

Within the config I **changed** the following property:

`workgroup = WORKGROUP`

Now it is equal with the Windows 10 workstation domain.

When finished I ran the following command:

`smbclient -L W10` (where W10 is the IP of my Windows 10). I made sure the host is pingable before

Following prompt appears:

```
Enter WORKGROUP/root's password: *****
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

The password was actually right so there is something else not working. I also wonder how to change the username `WORKGROUP/root` it appends automatically. Because the login username of my machine is `xetra11` and not `root`

Comment: Are you operating as root in Gnu/Linux?

Comment: yes sir I am root at my arch linux

Comment: Operating as root, is contraindicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the username. If you don't it uses your local username.

From the man page, add `-U «username»`. So `smbclient -U xetra11 -L W10`